# .NET versions in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

In the new ASP.NET 5 projects, there are multiple ways / places to control the .NET versions:

- In `global.json`
- In Project -> Properties, Application tab, Solution DNX SDK Version (this is the same as the global.json)
- In Project -> Properties, Debug tab, Use Specific Runtime
- In Package Manager Console, using `dnvm list`
- In a normal console in the application root, using `dnvm list`

Which of these are the same (apart from the first two) and what do they all do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dnx` in `global.json` is only used by VS. No one else uses it and if you run the application outside of VS, there is no guarantee that it'll use that version.

The `dnx` used to run a particular application is set in two ways:

1. Either pass the full path to a particular `dnx`. E.g: `C:\dnx\dnx.exe . run`
2. The `dnx` on the PATH resolved according to your OS' PATH resolution (we don't control that).

When you run `dnvm use <version>`, that particular version is added to the path and it will be used by that particular process and it's child processes. If you run `dnvm use -p <version>`, that version of `dnx` is added to the user's PATH in addition to the process' PATH.

For VS, if no version is specified in `global.json` by default it uses the `dnx` under the `default` alias. The default alias is updated when you run `dnvm upgrade` or `dnvm use -p`

Comment: If I'm using the Package Manager Console in VS in my project, I get a different version than whatever I've set in global and the project properties. So how does that work?! Because I'd like to run ef migrations from the PM Console, but I'm getting dependency resolution errors that I can't seem to fix...

Comment: Why the need to have that `global.json` setting? So confusing

Comment: The setting in `global.json` is just for VS to know what DTH (Design Time Host) to load. Otherwise, if you have multiple versions installed, you might not be able to compile